# Writing a DataSnap client with Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi, delphi-prism, datasnap

I'm trying to write a datasnap client using Delphi Prism in Visual Studio 2010. when I try to create a Data Connection (in Server Explorer), using DataSnap provider, I get this error:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Comment: Don't have a definitive answers, so here are a few links instead: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2009/03/25/31442  and http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26874  BTW, You're supposed to use the `ADO.net` provider

Comment: doesn't help me. how can I generate proxy unit in Prism? I generated proxy in Delphi and imported into VS2010 (Prism) but doesn't compile.

Comment: The best would be to drop DataSnap. In the .Net world, DataSnap introduces just another not required layer with a *lot* of bugs. You'd be way better of if you use technologies built into .NET or a *real* Multi-Tier framework. DataSnap just causes problems from end to end.

Comment: I love to do so, but in our company there are a few Delphi developers and a lot of implemented modules in Delphi and we hope to be able to use them in Delphi Prism or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Seems .net configuration file has been corrupted. I think it had been broken after I installed Delphi XE or Delphi XE2. Everything worked greate when I fixed the corrupted file.

answer is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vseditor/thread/7b4f353b-77fd-427c-976b-5968abc88c13